# Run function in script from command line (Node JS) using ES6 Modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I just want to be able to run a specific function inside of a JS File ES6 Modules with Node.JS from the command line...

For example, I have a file called schedules.js which has the following function

```
export function name(params) {
  console.log('Hello World');
}
```

I want to be able to run that function by typing the following command in the command line:

`node schedules.js name`

The way I am trying to run that now, I just get nothing from as output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use command line arguments. For getting command line arguments you can use process.argv. Maybe you can change your program something like that:

```
function name(params) {
  console.log("Hello World");
}
if (process.argv[2] === "name") {
  name("");
}
```

Now when you write  "node schedules.js name" to your terminal your function will be called.

Comment: Just wanted to add that if you were doing this as a debug config in VSCode, your launch.json would look something like ```{ "type": "node", "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\schedules.js", "args": ["name"] }```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to export your function from the module. Just have nodeJs run the function but make sure you call your function in that module with the [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments/) arguments that you pass in to it.

```
function schedules(name) {
  return name;
}

const name = process.argv[2];

console.log(schedules(name));
```

---

```
node schedules.js Lucas
```